# Create Exception on Mime filtering on squid

Tags: squid, ubuntu-12.04, mime-type

I have a server with the operating system Ubuntu 12:04 LTS version. I also paired the squid version 3.1.19 on my server. with the client about 30 units.

to prevent my clients to download any files and streaming, I use

> acl xxx rep_mime_type application/octet-stream

during limited hours. Of course with

> http_reply_access deny xxx

But I see that the anti-virus update (average client using avast) on squid logs to participate blocked. the question is, how is that files of a particular site made ​​an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Create additional [ACLs](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl) that identifies the domains, networks, ports, whatever that you want to make an exception for.

Place an `http_reply_access allow aclname` before your `http_reply_access deny xxx`.

Comment: Well i've tried its work, thanks :), I so confuse with the ACL. This is what i've done : I make an acl as your aswered above.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i've done
I create acl

```
acl xxx rep_mime_type application/octet-stream
acl xyz dstdomain "/etc/squid3/allowdest"
```

then i put

```
http_reply_access allow xyz
http_reply_access deny xxx
```

where the `/etc/squid3/allowdest` is contain with address that should be allowed